# How to change the fontFamily of a CardInputWidget (Stripe)

Tags: android, stripe-payments, android-styles, android-fonts

I'm trying to theme a `CardInputWidget` to match the rest of my app, but I cant seem to apply the `android:fontFamily="@font/font_name"` item directly to the view or with a style or theme.

This is `com.stripe:stripe-android:5.1.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experimentation, setting `android:fontFamily` via style used in an `android:theme` attribute just doesn't work.

However, I can use this method to search a `CardInputWidget` for all `TextView` children and change their typeface at runtime:

```
public static void setTypeface(Typeface tf, View v) {
    if (v instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) v).setTypeface(tf);
    }
    else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;

        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            setTypeface(tf, vg.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it is pretty straightforward:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL);
CardInputWidget card = findViewById(R.id.card);

setTypeface(tf, card);
```

Comment: is there any way to change the hint color and font?

Answer (score 0):

you can use theme attribute theme for custom font. i have given code snap below

```
  // use this in card
         <com.stripe.android.view.CardInputWidget
            android:id="@+id/card_input_widget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/textRegular"      <---- use this
              />


 <style name="textRegular" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
</style>
```